# IDisposable implementation: do the default recommendations apply when using Blazor wasm?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, idisposable

I'm wondering if the default rules specified on the [Implement a Dispose method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose) still apply when writing classes/components for Blazor (specifically on the `SuppressFinalize`method call, which is nowhere to be seen on blazor wasm samples I've seen).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the default rules specified on the Implement a Dispose method still apply ...

No.

But then again, they don't apply to application code on other platforms either.
From that same page:

> Therefore, we recommend that you construct System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle objects instead of implementing a finalizer.

So you shouldn't write Finalizers (in C#: `~MyClass() {}`) and without Finalizers you don't need `SuppressFinalize`.  In Blazor Wasm it's all n/a anyway, you don't have unmanaged resources there.

The complexity that remains is the `virtual Dispose(bool)` pattern. That has everyhing to do with derived classes that need IDisposable too.
We usually ignore this, and when you can make your class `sealed` you're good. Otherwise follow the pattern.